# If $\lim_{x \to -3} \dfrac{f(x) -2 }{x + 3} = 2$ then find $\lim_{x \to -3} f(x)$

Tags: calculus, limits

Calculus question here regarding the evaluation of limits with denominator that seems to divide by zero. 
This question is interesting because multiplying by the conjugate of the denominator doesn't work.

Would need some help on this. Thanks!

> Given that
>
> $$\lim_{x \to -3} \frac{f(x)-2}{x+3} = 2$$
>
> evaluate
>
> $$\lim_{x \to -3} f(x)$$

Comment: Indeed, I believe there are many options for f(x), as long as the limit of the fraction gives 2. Thus it is not viable to determine what f(x) is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because $\lim\limits_{x\to -3} \displaystyle\frac{f(x)-2}{x+3}$ there exist and clearly $\lim\limits_{x\to -3} (x+3)$ there exist, then the product of the limits there exist and moreover, is the product of limits, i.e., $$0=2(0)=\lim\limits_{x\to -3} \displaystyle\frac{f(x)-2}{x+3} \lim\limits_{x\to -3}(x+3)=\lim\limits_{x\to -3} \frac{f(x)-2}{x+3} (x+3)=\lim\limits_{x\to -3} f(x)-2$$Now, because $\lim\limits_{x\to -3}2$ clearly there exist, then, the sum of the limits there exist and moreover, is the sum of the limits, i.e., $$\lim\limits_{x\to-3} f(x)= \lim\limits_{x\to-3}2+f(x)-2=\lim\limits_{x\to -3} 2 + \lim\limits_{x\to -3} f(x)-2=2+0=2$$Thus, $\lim\limits_{x\to-3} f(x)=2$

Comment: Simple and very clearly explained. Perfect +1

Comment: The second equation should be reworded as $$\lim f(x) =\lim f(x) - 2+2=\lim f(x) - 2+\lim 2=0+2=2$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$\lim_{x\to-3}{x+3}=0.$$

Hence, as $x$ goes to $-3$, the denominator goes to 0.  Then the only way for

$$\lim_{x \to -3} \frac{f(x)-2}{x+3}$$

to not go to infinity as the denominator goes to 0 is if the numerator also goes to 0.  Hence

$$\lim_{x\to-3}{f(x)-2}=0,$$

so

$$\lim_{x\to-3}{f(x)}=2.$$

Comment: But 0/0 is also undefined. And this approach does not use the information provided that the limit of the given fraction equals to 2.

Comment: The justification of "then only way for... to not go to infinity" is via enumeration of cases about limit of $f$ (limit exists as zero/non-zero, diverges or oscillates). It is much simpler to use algebra of limits (like other answer here) to find limit of $f$.